# SQLite Swift Binding and Retrieving

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I am having an issue with either the binding and inserting of data or the retrieval of my data. I'm honestly not sure how to determine which is causing the issue. I am trying to add a `textfield`, `latitude`, and `longitude` to the database using the code below. I am almost positive the problem lies with the `sqlite3_bind_text` or the `sqlite3_column_text` functions but I am including both the functions in their entirety for context. When I run my debug print statements every value is printed out as the longitude value. Almost as if the longitude value is overwriting the other two columns? Is the way I am passing `latitude` and `longitude` to bind incorrectly? Or am I retrieving the data incorrectly?

```
@IBAction func submitPressed(_sender: UIButton) {

    var lat = ""
    var long = ""

    if(isLocationEnabled.isOn == true){
        enableLocationManager()
        let location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = locationManager.location!.coordinate
        lat = String(location.latitude)
        long = String(location.longitude)
        print(lat)
        print(long)

    } else {
        disableLocationManager()
        lat = "44.5"
        long = "-123.2"
    }

    let text = textEntered.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)


    if(text?.isEmpty)!{
        textEntered.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    }

    var statement: OpaquePointer?

    let newQuery = "INSERT INTO Location (textEntered, latitude, longitude) VALUES (?,?,?)"

    if sqlite3_prepare(database, newQuery, -1, &statement, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
        let error = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(database)!)
        print("Error Preparing: \(error)")
        return
    }

    if sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, text, -1, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
        let error = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(database)!)
        print("Error Binding: \(error)")
        return
    }

    if sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, lat, -1, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
        let error = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(database)!)
        print("Error Binding: \(error)")
        return
    }

    if sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, long, -1, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
        let error = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(database)!)
        print("Error Binding: \(error)")
        return
    }

    if sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE {
        let error = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(database)!)
        print("Error Inserting: \(error)")
        return
    }

    textEntered.text = ""
```

Then, I try to retrieve it using the code below:

```
func readValues() {
    posts.removeAll()

    let newQuery = "SELECT id, textEntered, latitude, longitude FROM Location"

    var statement: OpaquePointer?

    if sqlite3_prepare(database, newQuery, -1, &statement, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
        let error = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(database)!)
        print(error)
    }

    while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        let id = sqlite3_column_int(statement,0)
        let textEntered = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(statement,1))
        let latitude = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(statement,2))
        let longitude = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(statement,3))


        print("Text Entered: \(textEntered)")
        print("Latitude: \(latitude)")
        print("Longitude: \(longitude)")

        posts.append(Post(id: Int(id),textEntered: String(describing: textEntered), latitude: String(describing: latitude), longitude: String(describing: longitude)))
    }

    self.tableViewPosts.reloadData()

}
```

EDIT: I was able to determine that there is a flaw in the insert. When I view the SQLite database through DB Browser I see that the longitude value is being inserted into all of the columns. I'm just not sure where my syntax is flawed in the sqlite3_bind_text.
[image]

Comment: `sqlite3_bind_xxx` indexes are 1-based. `sqlite3_column_xxx` indexes are 0-based. Never use `SELECT * ...`. Explicitly list the columns you want to query.

Comment: This makes sense. I'm just not sure how my indexes are incorrect since I am not binding the id but I am retrieving the id in column_text (i.e. 0 for id).

Comment: Read the 2nd half of my comment.

Comment: @rmaddy Right, I changed the query and my column indexes are 0-based (see revised code above) yet all of my variables are printing the `longitude` value still

Answer (score 2):

I figured out there was an issue with the `sqlite3_bind_text`. I changed the three columns from

```
if sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, text, -1, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
        let error = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(database)!)
        print("Error Binding: \(error)")
        return
}
```

to

```
 if sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, text, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK {
            let error = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(database)!)
            print("Error Binding: \(error)")
            return
}
```

where SQLITE_TRANSIENT is defined as

```
let SQLITE_TRANSIENT = unsafeBitCast(OpaquePointer(bitPattern: -1), to: sqlite3_destructor_type.self)
```